# Unable to connect to Windows Azure from Powershell Azure Powershell module

Tags: windows, powershell, azure

I created my account on Windows Azure, also downloaded and installed my Azure Powershell module (I'm able to execute azure command and see the help message). Then I downloaded my publish settings file and tried to import it using Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile . I don't get any output message for this execution.

The problem comes when I  run any command that tries to connect to my Azure subscription, for example:

```
PS > Get-AzureLocation

Get-AzureLocation : Please connect to internet before executing this cmdlet
```

I have internet connection in my machine and my execution policy is RemoteSigned.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To see is there some result from Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile you can call:

```
Get-AzureSubscription
```

By default it select the default to current subscription. If you don't see any result then you don't import your subscription settings right.

This [Introduction to Windows Azure PowerShell](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Virtual-Machines-and-Networking-Tutorials/Introduction-to-Windows-Azure-PowerShell) also can help you.