# Azure Powershell Error - Connect to Internet

Tags: powershell, azure

I am having the same issue as over here.....
[Unable to connect to Windows Azure from Powershell Azure Powershell module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156435/unable-to-connect-to-windows-azure-from-powershell-azure-powershell-module)

I can verify that the machine I am running the Powershell script from has Internet Access. I successfully ran Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile which launched me a browser to download my settings from azure.

I have successfully imported the settings
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile

This is verified by checking my AppData\Roaming\Windows Azure Powershell
and this contains my settings correctly.

When I try to access any cmdlets, Get-AzureSubscription etc I am returned with the same error outlined above "Please connect to internet before executing this cmdlet".

I have searched high and low on Google and no success.

Sorry, it seems I didn't include my setup for my Build Server:...
Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit.
Microsoft .NET 4.0.
Also a DNS, DHCP, RRAS Server (RRAS only for VPN DialIn. My Gateway is a router elsewhere in my network).
Windows Advanced Firewall (However, all Profiles Turned Off, so not in use at the moment).
Powershell v3.0.
Latest Powershell Tools as of yesterday from WindowsAzure Downloads (Last updated 2013 according to website).
My Azure Subscription is Pay-As-You-Go in North Europe.
My ISP is Virgin Media.

I can successfully Ping from Powershell, so can confirm powershell has access to the internet. my IPv4 is a static address which is correct and has DNS and Gateway settings set correctly. Under Internet Options, I do indeed have "Never Dial a Connection" set as the only 2 connections in the list are VPN Connections. I have however tried with the settings changed.  I am currently checking to see if Powershell Azure cmdlets will work from my development laptop instead.

Has anyone any ideas?

Comment: Could there be a proxy in picture or maybe firewall configured to block certain websites?

Comment: Unforunately not. I can access Azure Management and the Firewall is turned off for all Profiles from my Build Server

Answer (score 4):

I looked into the code for the PowerShell Cmdlet on Github (https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools) and found that to check Internet connectivity, the code makes use of [`InternetGetConnectedState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384702%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in `WinInet.dll` (Source code here: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools/blob/master/WindowsAzurePowershell/src/Management.Utilities/Common/Validate.cs).

Then I searched for why `InternetGetConnectedState` function would return false even though the computer is connected to the Internet, I landed on the following page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315035. Can you check if this is not causing the problem you're facing?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmmm. This is interesting. I have just checked my settings and I do have a default gateway set correctly and is pointing to the correct address. I have also checked the Internet Options "Never Dial a connection". This was indeed set to true. I have tried it set to Only when a connection is not alive. This made no difference though. :( Thanks for the detailed help though. I'll keep investigating...

Comment: Can you also share the OS and other details of your build server? You may want to try the same cmdlet through another computer so that issue can be localized to a particular machine.

Comment: I will try it on my Development Laptop.

Comment: I have just tried to execute on my development laptop, Windows 7, and I can successfully connect to Azure through Powershell. So it just seems that my Build Server outlined above cannot.